# EF DbSet.SqlQuery with TPH inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using EF 6 I am trying to retrieve a set of entities leveraging [DBset.SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery.aspx), however the entities are a hierarchy of classes inheriting from a single abstract class in a single table (TPH) and I see the following error as a result:

> InvalidOperationException: Instances of abstract classes cannot be
>   created.

This is a simple case. The entities have a unique `id` key and the reason to try use SqlQuery is to retrieve a set of `id` in one query only instead of calling `Find` multiple times in a loop:

```
myContext.myHierarchy.Find(eachId)
```

I tried to use:

```
List<myBaseClass> myResult = myContext.myHierarchy.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.myHierarchy AS a INNER JOIN @theIDs AS i ON a.id = i.id",mySqlParameter).ToList();
```

The SqlParameter is a user defined table type as just a column of int.

This approach produced the error mentioned above.

Comment: Why don't you  just use the `DbSet` with a `Contains` query?

Comment: Would that be: myContext.myHierarchy.Where(a => theIDs.Contains(a.id)) ? You are right that can work in this case. However I would propose to keep the question to be able to use SqlQuery in other queries against TPH

Comment: That question isn't too interesting: it just isn't supported in SqlQuery (and won't ever be in EF6)

Comment: @GertArnold Unfortunately, I cannot take time to isolate a small and illustrative test-case to support my claim. But EF6's code that compiles linq queries to sql is slow. What's worse, EF6 isn't capable of caching the compiled sql if the original query has `Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))`. So the compilation overhead on the order of 200-500ms is present every time such a query is performed. If you feel like it, start up a profiler and take a look.

Comment: Ridiculous that this isn't supported. It builds a query, executes it, and interprets the results into the right TPH type in every scenario, but for some reason, if you write the query yourself, even though you're returning the same fields, it cannot simply switch on the discriminator and create the correct type. Then it bury's the methods that do so in internal classes making it impossible to do it yourself. We'd be better off sticking with sprocs.

Comment: EF builds TPH queries like: `CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = 1024) THEN '0X0X0X' WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = 2048) THEN '0X0X1X' WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = 4096) THEN '0X0X1X0X'`...  like why use cryptic codes like that for the derived types. Why not just return all the records, and construct a type based on the discriminator, then populate the fields for that type.  Simple.  But no, they choose to do it the hard way.  And then EF Core apparently has LESS mapping support!? WOw.